# How can I fix graphql error: Must provide document?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm using [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga). My query works in GraphiQL and curl but doesn't work when I send them in React.

Here's the error I receive:

```
Error: Must provide document
    at invariant (.../node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:21:11)
    at Object.validate (.../node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:53:41)
    at doRunQuery (.../node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:111:42)
    at .../node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:21:56
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

When I send a CURL it works:

```
curl 'http://localhost:4000/graphql' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:4000' -H 'Authorization: XXX' --data-binary '{"query":"query { get_me { user { email } }}"}' --compressed
```

but when I add it to React app, it doesn't:

```
export const myQuery = () => ({
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',

  options: {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'ABC',
    },
  },

  body: {
    data: '{"query":"get_user { user { email } }"}',
  },
```

Comment: Why are you complicating your quaries like that just use react-apollo which takes cares of everything else and you just need to send only query. Just read the docs here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

Comment: @Nux thanks for the suggestion! Currently I want to modify my source code as little as possible and just test GraphQL without its nice features.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: I should use

```
body: {
    query: 'query { get_user { user { email } } }',
  },
```

instead of

```
body: {
    data: '{"query":"get_user { user { email } }"}',
  },
```